# Difference between speed and configured clock speed

Tags: ram

When i type

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory
```

on terminal it shows speed `1800MHz` and configured speed `1600 MHz`. what is difference between them? I want to purchase RAM. Which frequency RAM should I purchase?

[image]

Comment: How many memory modules do you have installed?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Select the text, copy it to the clipboard, then paste it in a code block. That being said, your memory module is a 4 GiB [Micron Technology MT9JSF51272PZ-1G9E2](https://www.micron.com/parts/modules/ddr3-sdram/mt9jsf51272pz-1g9) DDR-3 RDIMM, industry standard designation  PC3-14900, capable of working at 1866 MHz, currently working at 1600 MHz (which is very usual). You need to buy DDR-3 RDIMM memory, PC3-14900, 1866 MHz, 1.5 V, CL 13 or lower.  If possible, buy another 4 GiB DIMM module so that the motherboard can use dual-channel access if it's capable.

Comment: Got my answer. thnx